# Join strings on different lines depending on indentation with awk

Tags: awk

I have this multiline string:

```bash
foo
foobar
  bar
  baz
    bat
bar
```

and I'd like to end up with:

```bash
foo
foobar.bar
foobar.baz
foobar.baz.bat
bar
```

My thinking would be that for each line, I'd have to look at all of the following lines to check whether the next `n` strings begin with a certain number of spaces, and depending on the number of spaces I'd have to format the string accordingly.

Is this possible with awk?

Comment: Yes, it is possible with awk. Have you tried anything yourself yet? If so please [edit] your question to show your attempt.

Comment: Is that the literal document you are working with, or do you have something that is an actual YAML document or in some other known structured format?

Comment: @Kusalananda that is the literal document

Comment: It looks like you can do this using just one line of look-ahead, keeping an array of the current indent and string. For any line where the indent increases, you just store it. If the indent does not increase, you can emit the previous complete line. If the indent reduces, you can reduce the array. EOF counts as zero indent. Basically, you are walking a tree of which you have only seen the left-hand side.

Comment: It looks as if you are either missing `foobar`, or `foobar.baz` shouldn't be in the output.

Comment: To follow-up on @Kusalananda's comment, if the missing `foobar` line in the expected output is not an oversight, please clarify on what ground it is to be omitted.

Comment: `foobar` is not mentioned in the output, because it has children. But `baz` has children **and** is mentioned in the output alone without them first.  I think this is what @Kusalandra is getting at.

Answer (score 1):

With `perl`:

```bash
<your-file expand | perl -lpe '
  ($indent, $txt) = /^( *)(.*)/;
  $depth = length($indent) / 2;
  $part[$depth] = $txt;
  $_ = join ".", @part[0..$depth]'
```

Or golfed:

```
<your-file expand|perl -lpe'
  my$d;/^(  (?{$d++}))*/;$p[$d]=$'\'';$_=join".",@p[0..$d]'
```

(also allowing the text to start with one space character if there's an odd number of spaces at the start of the line).

`expand` expands TABs if any into spaces, assuming tab stops every 8 columns, but that can be changed with options.

An `awk` equivalent could be:

```bash
<your-file expand | awk '
  BEGIN {
    OFS = "."
    while ((getline line) > 0) {
      match(line, /^ */)
      $ (NF = RLENGTH / 2 + 1) = substr(line, RLENGTH + 1)
      print
    }
  }'
```

Note that they give:

```
foo
foobar
foobar.bar
foobar.baz
foobar.baz.bat
bar
```

I'm assuming the missing `foobar` line in your expected output is an oversight.

Comment: I missed processing tabs initially in my answer ... Then, looking at your code, I remembered and added them. +1

Answer (score 1):

Assuming [GNU `gawk`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) ... No fault proofing included though(*Taking your word for: ["that is the literal document"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/747203/join-strings-on-different-lines-depending-on-indentation-with-awk#comment1421123_747203)*) ... So,:

```
$ cat file
foo
foobar
  bar
  baz
    bat
bar
$
$ gawk 'BEGIN {
    PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@ind_num_asc"
}

{
    match($0, /^[ \t]*/)
    if (RLENGTH == 0) {
        if (NR > 1 && length(a) == 1) {
            print a[0]
        }
        delete a
        a[0] = $0
        lsnum = RLENGTH
    }
    if (RLENGTH > lsnum) {
        lsnum = RLENGTH
        a[lsnum] = "." substr($0, RLENGTH + 1)
        p = 1
    }
    if (p == 1) {
        for (i in a) {
            printf "%s", a[i]
        }
        print ""
        lsnum = 0
        p = 0
    }
}

END {
    if (length(a) == 1) {
        print a[0]
    }
}' file
foo
foobar.bar
foobar.baz
foobar.baz.bat
bar
```

That should work if the lines in your file are preceded with either spaces or tabs … However, for a mix of the two, you might need to tweak a bit to e.g. parse tabs into spaces or vice versa to avoid duplicate indices which will set the wrong array elements and result in faulty output.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pretend that the data is actually a YAML document containing nothing but `null` values at various paths.  We may do this by adding `:` at the end of the lines in the data in the question:

```bash
$ sed 's/$/:/' file
foo:
foobar:
  bar:
  baz:
    bat:
bar:
```

This allows us to ask a YAML parser for all the available paths in the document.

---

With [Andrey Kislyuk's `yq`](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/):

```bash
$ sed 's/$/:/' file | yq -r 'paths | join(".")'
foo
foobar
foobar.bar
foobar.baz
foobar.baz.bat
bar
```

The `paths` filter of `jq` (which `yq` is a wrapper around) outputs a set of arrays representing all the paths in the given document.  The `join()` call joins these lists into dot-delimited strings.

Avoiding listing the intermediate paths can be done by selecting only the paths that have `null` values (`not` is a shorter way of writing `. == null`):

```bash
$ sed 's/$/:/' file | yq -r 'paths(not) | join(".")'
foo
foobar.bar
foobar.baz.bat
bar
```

Note that this removes the intermediate paths `foobar` and `foobar.baz`.

---

With [Mike Farah's `yq`](https://mikefarah.gitbook.io/yq/):

```bash
$ sed 's/$/:/' file | yq '.. | map(path | join(".")) | .[]'
foo
foobar
bar
foobar.bar
foobar.baz
foobar.baz.bat
```

We need to explicitly recurse over the document's values with Mike's `yq`, and to arrange to call `path` and `join()` on the values as we get to them.

You can do it with the shorter expression `..|path|join(".")` too,
but then you'll get an extra empty line in the output.

Would you want to avoid outputting the intermediate paths:

```bash
$ sed 's/$/:/' file | yq '.. | map(select(not) | path | join(".")) | .[]'
foo
bar
foobar.bar
foobar.baz.bat
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution in [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr).  The approach is to build a nested tree out of the items which can then be easily printed in the dot notation (or analyzed in interesting ways). This handles items which are suddenly indented by an excessive number of levels, as can be seen in the handling of the extended input file `input2`, and also cases of unexpected deindentation.

```
$ cat input2
foo
foobar
  bar
  baz
    bat
bar
xyzzy
      out1
      out2
stretched
      way
          out
weird
      indent
    deindent
$ txr code.tl < input2
foo
foobar
foobar.bar
foobar.baz
foobar.baz.bat
bar
xyzzy
xyzzy.out1
xyzzy.out2
stretched
stretched.way
stretched.way.out
weird
weird.indent
weird.deindent
```

Onto the code in `code.tl`:

```
(defsymacro indent "  ")

(defun deindent (items)
  (mapcar (do if (starts-with indent @1)
            (drop (len indent) @1)
            @1)
          items))

(defun indent-to-tree (lines)
  (let ((pieces (partition-if (opip (starts-with indent @2) not) lines)))
    (append-matches (@(as piece (@head . @tail)) pieces)
      (cond
        ((starts-with indent head)
         (while* (starts-with indent (car piece))
           (upd piece deindent))
         (indent-to-tree piece))
        (t (list (cons head (indent-to-tree (deindent tail)))))))))

(defun dot-notation (items)
  (build
    (each ((item items))
      (tree-bind (node . children) item
        (add node)
        (each ((dnc (dot-notation children)))
          (add `@node.@dnc`))))))

(flow (get-lines) indent-to-tree dot-notation tprint)
```

At the top level, the workflow is organized by the `flow` macro: standard input is turned into a list of strings via `(get-lines)` which is then piped through `indent-to-tree` to get a tree structure, which is then converted via `dot-notation` into a list of strings, which is then dumped as lines on standard output via `tprint`.

The conversion of a tree is a recursive process. Each level of the recursion starts by breaking the list of lines into groups such each line which is not indented begins a new group.

We can see what this looks like at the REPL:

```
1> (flow (file-get-lines "input2")
         (partition-if (opip (starts-with indent @2) not)))
(("foo") ("foobar" "  bar" "  baz" "    bat") ("bar") ("xyzzy" "      out1" "      out2")
 ("stretched" "      way" "        out") ("weird" "      indent" "    deindent"))
```

The `indent-to-tree` function does this partitioning and then iterates over the pieces, handling the two major cases: indent-only group or indented group headed by non-indented line. The cases are processed recursively. In the indent-only group, we iteratively de-indent the lines until the first line is no longer indented, then recurse on it.

When we apply `indent-to-tree` to the lines from `input2`, it looks like this:

```
2> (flow (file-get-lines "input2") indent-to-tree)
(("foo") ("foobar" ("bar") ("baz" ("bat"))) ("bar") ("xyzzy" ("out1") ("out2"))
 ("stretched" ("way" ("out"))) ("weird" ("indent") ("deindent")))
```

This is the tree representation: the top-level of the tree is a list of items. Each items is a head string (referred to in the code as `node`) followed by zero or more child items. For instance `("foo")` has the head string `"foo"` with no children. Whereas `("foobar" ....)` has head `"foobar"` with children `("bar")` and `("baz" ("bat"))`. The second of these has a child `("bat")`, which itself has no children.

This representation is turned into the dot notation by a simple recursive procedure which is almost just a footnote in this whole thing. `dot-notation` relies on the `build` macro which creates a lexical environment for procedurally building a list. Inside `build`, we can use `(add ...)` to add items to the list. `add` appears twice: the head string is added, so that `foobar` is listed without children, and then it's also listed again for each child, with the dot notation of that child attached.

##### Notes:

- Everything still works if we define `indent` as `" "` (one space), so we should, because that handles more cases, like indentations not aligned to multiples of two space.
- Squeezing out blank lines would be a good idea; this is not done, and the behavior is not nice.
- The predicate function in `partition-if` is a two-argument function, which is why the `op` syntax references parameter `@2`.  `partition-if` calls the function with successive, overlapping pairs of elements. When the function returns true, it divides the sequence right between those elements. E.g.

  ```
  ;; start new partition whenever an element is smaller
  ;; than its predecessor.
  (partition-if (op > @1 @2) '(1 2 3 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3))
  --> ((1 2 3 4) (3) (2) (1) (0 1 2 3))
  ```
- `while*` is a variant of `while` which does a bottom-of-loop test. Another way to look at it is that it skips the loop guard before the first iteration, executing the body unconditionally, and then behaves like `while`.